# ImageView Declaration

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I have the following in my `mainActivity()`` :

```
class Config 
{
    int position;
    int index;
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Config[] config = new config[10];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    config[0].index=0;
}
}
```

which gives a `java.lang.NullPointerException` upon the assignment of `config[0].index=0;`

I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you assign `config[0]`? It's `null` until you assign it.

Answer (score 1):

Initially(At creation time) array object hold null references. You need to create `config` Object.

```
Config[0] = new config();
Config[0].index=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:*** To avoid confusion and for your better understanding, I am renaming `config` (with small c) as `configObj` in my code snippet below.

So, `Config` is a class and `configObj` is an object representing the class.

Use:

```
Config[] configObj = new Config[10]; 
configObj [0] = new Config();   // Initialize the object.
configObj [0].index=0;
```

or use

```
for(int i=0;i<10;1++)
{
    configObj [i] = new Config();
}
configObj [0].index = 0;
configObj [5].position = 5; // and so on......
```